# Extend RAID 5 to use unused space and add additional disks?

Tags: raid, hp, raid5, hp-smart-array

I am new to RAID. I want to extend an existing RAID 5.

The current setup is as follows:

```
Array A
unused space : 349956 MB


logical drive :1
total size 273GB
raid5
disk : /dev/cciss/c0d0

physical 
1I:1:5 - 146gb
2I:1:1 - 146gb
2I:1:2 - 146gb
2I:1:3 - 146gb
2I:1:4 - 146gb

I also have 2 more unassigned disks if it helps.
1I:1:6
1I:1:7
```

I want to use unused space. How can I extend the array using unused space or should I create new array of unused space?

If I want to use my unused drives too, how I can extend the existing array to include them?
I dont want to lose any data, because this server is in production.

Updates-

hardware - Hp ProLiant DL380 G5
total 7 HDD of 146GB
OS - Centos 5

I have installed the "hpacucli" command.

All help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS, hardware or software RAID, what controller, etc?

Comment: @MDMarra Since it's /dev/cciss/c0d0 It's an HP controller of some kind.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Right, but their StorageWorks line also uses those controllers. He doesn't even say what this box is. If it's something like, say, a P4000 series SAN node, it's going to be a lot different of an answer than if it's a DL380 G7.

Answer (score 1):

This is an HP ProLiant with an 8-bay cage. You haven't provided enough decent information, though.

In general, you have a choice as to whether to expand your array with unassigned disks and either increase your RAID 5 to consume the unused space *OR* create a new logical drive within that unused space. The new logical drive does not have to be RAID 5. It can be RAID 0, 1+0, 5 or 6... The amount of available space will vary based on that choice. The data will be redistributed amongst the physical disks comprising the array.

The [HP Smart Array reference guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c00729544/c00729544.pdf) has a a chapter on array expansion and other operations. Read through and decide what you want.

Edit:

You will need a combination of `hpacucli` commands on your Smart Array P400 controller. The easier/safer approach is to do this offline and graphically using the [bootable SmartStart CD](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884083&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D3884082%257CprodNameId%253D3884083%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-fa4e107ffbbd4ef394e57dd739%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). It can also be done online if you have the full [HP Management Agents](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3884083&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D3884082%257CprodNameId%253D3884083%257CswEnvOID%253D4004%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-ce781be0e6924ce3bab971f01a%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) installed, but the path of least resistance is to use the bootable CD.

Also, if you don't need the space, you could convert this array to RAID 1+0 in the process. But that's [another discussion](https://serverfault.com/a/339214/13325).

Comment: hpacucli ctrl slot=1 logicaldrive 1 modify size=max 
Will the above command will help me?

Comment: Something like that. See my edit above.